# How do you shift a selection in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

When you've selected a slice of track in Audacity, how do you shift the selection window without shifting the content?

I'm trying to preview the playback of specific slices of audio in exact lengths, and I want to shift my selection by a few seconds so I can playback the same length of audio but at different start indexes. Currently I have to manually re-selection the portion, whereas I'd like to be able to just drag the selection window, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Type the selection range in to the selection start and length input boxes in the lower part of the window. You can set a default length and just change the selection start value to cover the different ranges you wish to play back.